# How do I only encode and decode particular column in sql table and take it into stringBuilder?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have one sql table `MyTable` in that table in one column having `encoded html text` I want to `take that text in decoded format and fill the dataset`.

`MyTable`

```
Name  Address  Text
aaa   IND      '&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;&amp;lt;p class=&amp;quot;MsoNormal&amp;quot;          
               style=&amp;quot;margin: 0in 0in  
               6pt;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;i&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&#39;color: rgb(7, 
               44, 149); line-height: 115%; font-family: &amp;quot;Segoe 
               UI&amp;quot;,&amp;quot;sans-serif&amp;quot;; font-size: 
               10pt;&#39;&amp;gt;Please Note: This is a
               computer generated.'
```

Now in c# I tried to fetch this data from `MyTable` like below

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.Append(string.Format("select * from MyTable"));
SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sb.ToString(), sqlConnection);
                    sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 3000;
                    sqlDataAdapter.Fill(ds);
```

> Now I want to decode Text column  , when I'm fetching.
>   How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
 HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()
```

See here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k.aspx